# How to use custom facts with rspec Puppet

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, facter

Is there a way I can use a custom fact while using rspec? My module works fine and the custom fact exists and works as intended when I do a puppet run on my agent, but when I try to use the same fact in rspec I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: it { should contain_class('zabbixconfig') }

     Puppet::PreformattedError:
       Evaluation Error: Unknown variable: 'pskkey_generate'. at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/zabbixconfig/spec/fixtures/modules/zabbixconfig/manifests/init.pp:46:13 on node puppet-master-poc
```

The `pskkey_generate` in the error above is my custom fact, and here's a snippet of my class including it:

```
$pskkey = $pskkey_generate
```

Does anyone know how to get rspec to recognize my custom fact? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `spec/spec_helper.rb` file you can add the following:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.default_facts = { :pskkey_generate => '...' }
end
```

See https://github.com/rodjek/rspec-puppet#default_facts

Comment: Thanks! I understand that the '...' needs to be replaced with the value of the pskkey_generate, but the pskkey_generate is a dynamically generated key. The command used to generate the key is `openssl rand -hex 32`. Since it's random, is there a way I can assign the value of the output to the pskkey_generate variable in the default_facts as well? If not I may just not unit test it for now and come back to it later.

Comment: Not really, as facts can behave differently on the host/OS that you're developing on versus the intended host/OS your code will run on. But by setting the fact to a known value, you can test that it affects your module in a known way. If the value just gets written out to a file, then you can add a test to check that with something like `it { is_expected.to contain_file('/some/file').with_content('abc123') }`, assuming you set the `pskkey_generate` fact to `abc123` in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it probably is best to hard code a known value of your fact in default_facts as bodgit suggests.  In other cases, when the fact comes from a third party module, it is annoying to have to add mocking to make realistic tests of your use of their code.

I have added at the top of my `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
if ENV.include? 'MODULEPATH'
  top_path = File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  ENV['FACTERLIB'] = ENV['MODULEPATH'].split(/:/).map do |p|
    p.start_with?('/') ? p : File.join(top_path, p)
  end.map do |p|
    Dir.glob(File.join(p, '*/lib/facter'))
  end.flatten.join(':')
end
```

When the Facter library loads, it will honour the FACTERLIB environment variable and evaluate all the custom facts supplied by the modules in your Puppet environment.

A typical value for `MODULEPATH` is "design:modules" when testing environments.